# How do I get more than one row from an SQL search using MIN/MAX/AVG

Tags: mysql, sql, max, distinct, min

I have a products table where each product has a color.  I need to return the minimum product price for each color.

```
SELECT MIN(price) FROM 'mytable' WHERE color="red"
```

will return the minimum price for all products colored red. And I get a single row returned.

What I need to do is return multiple rows with the minimum price for each distinct color.

But I don't know how to feed the results of a search to"WHERE" and get multiple rows.

I tried

```
SELECT MIN(price) FROM 'mytable' WHERE color=(SELECT DISTINCT color FROM 'mytable')
```

But I get an error. All my searches point to sub queries, but I can't figure out how to feed the sub query results to a query and get back multiple rows.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really explain what you want to do.  The single quotes around `'mytable'` are an automatic syntax error, so I assume that is a transcription issue.

Comment: Some people are getting confused. It sounds like all you want is a single row for each color, and that row to contain only two values: the color and minimum price for that color. Vashi's answer will give you that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` functionality:

```
SELECT color, MIN(price) FROM 'mytable' GROUP BY color;
```

This will give you minimum prices for each color in your data.

Comment: This was IT!  I got the results I needed, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.price = (select min(t2.price) from mytable t2 where t2.color = 'red');
```

Or, wait, I think you want the minimum price for each color.  Duh.  For that use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.price = (select min(t2.price) from mytable t2 where t2.color = t.color);
```

If you *only* want the minimum price, then aggregation is fine:

```
select color, min(price)
from mytable t
group by color;
```

The formulation of your query suggested (to me) that you want other columns as well.

Comment: This seems overcomplicated. Is there a reason why `SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY ...` wouldn't work?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris . . . Yes.  You appear to want all the columns on the row and you cannot get that with a `GROUP BY`.  In addition, you could have more than one row that has the minimum price for each color.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT color , MIN(price ) FROM 'mytable' GROUP BY color;
```

read more about group by in mysql doc . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

query return all colors values and min( price ) from each .

Comment: While this does provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the question with some explanation of how and why this solution works.